# Different iOS Today Extension Icon

Tags: ios, icons, today-extension

I'd like to change the little icon that's displayed on the left in the top bar of the actual widget in the notification center. I have a separate assets catalogues for the different targets with corresponding icons. In the project settings, the different targets are displayed with the correct icons but the extension still uses the host app's icon. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible at the moment. Sad but true.